# Symfony: How to change page shown after creating / editing an item?

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

I'm creating a very, very basic helpdesk system for a friend in Symfony. I have everything up and running now, but there are some usability issues that make the whole thing seem clunky.

The main problem is that after the user creates a new help ticket or edit an existing one, the next page they see is the edit page for that ticket. I would much prefer to show the user the ticket index. Does anyone know where and how I'd go about setting that up? I'm guessing there's a method I need to call in the Actions.class.php, but I just can't seem to figure out what it is.

(The editing/creating actions are more-or-less the ones Symfony auto-generated, with a little bit added to autofill a form, if that matters.)

I'm completely sure that this problem will take little work to fix, but I've really been struggling to Google this issue because of how common phrases like "next page" and such are. Any help will be very much appreciated!

Since I can't get code to newline properly in the comments, here's the last part of my update action:

```
public function executeUpdate(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    ...
$this->form = new NoteForm($note);
error_log("This line will be executed");
$this->processForm($request, $this->form);
error_log("This one won't.");
$this->setTemplate('index');
error_log("Neither will this one.");
$this->redirect('@homepage');
```

}

**SOLUTION:**
Just modify the redirect in the processForm definition in the actions.class.php for the item.

Answer (score 1):

in your actions file, there must be an edit or maybe update action, which creates/updates your ticket. At the end of this action, simply do a `$this->redirect('@ticket_index');` (ticket_index is the name of the ticket index route, which you can find in your routing.yml file).

Comment: That seems like exactly what I need, but putting the redirect at the end doesn't seem to work, because whatever's under the processForm call doesn't get executed. Do I need to find the processForm method in the code and modify that? (See edit above for what I tried)

Comment: Wow, nevermind, the processForm action is right there in the same file, and has the redirect already there for me to modify. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Paul Cozmas : glad you sorted it out! Since I didn't know what your file looked like, I couldn't be very precise...